# Which heroes in One Punch Man defeated dragon-level monsters?

Tags: one-punch-man

Aside from Saitama, which other heroes defeated dragon-level monsters in *One Punch Man*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three such unassisted defeats by two heroes in the manga.

> Flashy Flash defeats [Hellfire Flame](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Hellfire_Flame) and [Gale Wind](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Gale_Wind) simultaneously in manga Chapter 96;

> Child Emperor defeats [Phoenix Man](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Phoenix_Man) in manga Chapter 99.

If you count fights which involved multiple heroes, but no Saitama, then Melzargard, one of Boros's underlings, was defeated with the combined efforts of Bang, Metal Bat, Puri Puri Prisoner, and Atomic Samurai.

And honorable mentions from the webcomic:

> [Gums](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Gums) and [Fuhrer Ugly](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Fuhrer_Ugly) are both one-shot by Bang in chapter 72 (of the webcomic, of course, not the manga).  This occurs during a large multi-person battle once the Monster Association and Garou fights move to the surface. Other heroes were involved in this fight, but given the devastating one-shot nature of the takedowns, you might still count them as unassisted kills.  Gums had previously defeated both Pig God and (basically) Genos in one-on-one combat, and Fuhrer Ugly had defeated Sweet Mask.  Also in the webcomic and during essentially the same sequence, Tatsumaki effortlessly crushes Gyoro-Gyoro. When she then reveals Gyoro-Gyoro's hidden true identity, Tatsumaki is essentially defeated by a cleverly arranged sneak attack by this hidden identity and other monsters. So it's up to you to decide if this was a solo victory by Tatsumaki against a Dragon class threat or not.  That hidden identity is later defeated by Fubuki, though it's a lot more questionable if that counts as unassisted.  The other Dragon Class monsters are defeated either by combined efforts in a big battle, or by Saitama or Garou, or technically survived, or some combination thereof.

Comment: Flashy Flash defeated 2 dragon level monsters? Is he in another level to most of the S Class heroes? That would explain why he isnt afraid of Tatsumaki?

Comment: @Pablo Well Flashy Flash seems pretty arrogant in general, but he does at least have a track record to back it up. Tatsumaki certainly wouldn't consider her on his level, but she's at least as arrogant as Flashy Flash. We haven't seen every fight these characters have ever had, and sometimes they don't have a choice but to fight in groups, mind you.  That's just the situation that presents itself. The Web Comic is in the middle of something involving Flashy Flash so we might see and learn more about him in this regard, otherwise.

Comment: @Pablo Also, the Monster Association + Garou arc has not yet concluded in the manga, so possibly there will be altered or extra fights in what's left. Hellfire Flame and Gale Wind were not really in the webcomic, and were not Dragon class threats in the sense that they were, for example. And I think there's at least one other Dragon class threat in the manga already that didn't exist in the webcomic, and might be fought by a non-Saitama hero, but I'd have to double-check.

Answer (score 3):

Bang defeated

> [Melzargard](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Melzargard).

Child Emperor defeated

> [Phoenix Man](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Phoenix_Man).

Other than that, Saitama defeated

> some of the villains [here](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Dragon).

Comment: +1 for the ones mentioned but I've seen there is more. At least one more, probably more than one since I havent read the manga only the webcomic

Comment: Bang was working in concert with multiple other heroes on that.